# How to fix text overflow for paragraph text in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I am trying to make cards to display for my note taking app and if the user puts a lot of text there should be "..." at the end. In CSS that can be done by using `text-overflow: ellipsis;`
But its not working as shown:
[image: Screenshot]

all the text is overflowing out of the box. Also,  I am using bootstrap in my project and the way each card is made is here:

```js
let cardTemplate = `<div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${title.value}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            ${content.value}
                        </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Show More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
```

this is like a template for one card and I just add this to the div to display them.
I have given all of the resources now how can I fix the overflow of text?

Thanks for reading my query!

Comment: You also need `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;` for `text-overflow` to work.

Comment: @pistevw it is working but i have only one line how can make the text to fill all space and then have ellipses. And thank you so much I didn't know that

Comment: use overflow  "hidden" or "scroll" on card class like this :   .card{ overflow: hidden }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ellipses to show up by doing something like:

```css
.card-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But that will remove the line breaks so not likely something you want. You can remove the `white-space` directive but then you won't get the ellipses.

There's a good post on CSS Tricks on this and it shows a few alternative ways, none of which are great:
https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

**Edit**

Actually `webkit-line-clamp` might work for your use case..

```css
.card-text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 10;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing CSS property "white-space" this will tell that no space is available at the end of div so either line will break or behave like property given by user Please try to add below property with text-overflow property in CSS class.

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: I am able to see only one line due to this how can I have the text fill the area and then have ellipsis